# How to enable software rendering in lollipop?

Tags: android

I am working on an Android project where my device need to run by using software rendering.

My device architecture is ARM and I want to run lollipop using software rendering as my device dont have compatible hardware library file.

I came across that we need to set the flag `USE_OPENGL_RENDERER` to flase.
After setting also i am not getting the display ie getting android logo but not booting further.

What are the exact changes that i need to do in the source code to make it work with software rendering

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Android supports devices without OpenGL for a while.

[Android Compatibility Definition Document (CDD)](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/en//compatibility/android-cdd.pdf)

> 7.1.4. 2D and 3D Graphics Acceleration
>
> Device implementations MUST support both OpenGL ES 1.0 and 2.0, as embodied and detailed in the Android SDK
>   documentations.

Comment: In kitkat our fellow guys did software rendering. I followed the same in lollipop but now i am not getting it. Getting the android logo,but it is in infinite boot loop

Comment: It could be easily something else... why do you think rendering is too blame?

Comment: It could be easily something else means ? 
The software rendering is working? you mean to say

Comment: I'm assuming you are trying to bring up lollipop. So was it booting before? etc

Comment: Yes lollipop was booted with hardware OpenGL library. But our openGL library is not supported by lollipop as it is the older version. So I am not getting display when i tried with hardware openGL. So then i moved to software rendering and getting the android logo but its in infinite loop.